# How to change content of menu item when active

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I wanna change the actual content of my a element when it's active in the menu. fx from:

```
Home     Portfolio     About     Contact
```

to:

```
Home     {Portfolio}     About     Contact
```

Where portfolio is the active tag in this juncture.

Oh, and it's probably important to mention that it's for a one page scroll website?

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap uses ScrollSpy to do exactly what you're describing: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: What are you calling "active"?  `focus`, `hover`, current URL, `onClick`, `mouseenter`, `keydown`...

Comment: Can you show us some code? When active, is there a class applied to the active item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This jsFiddle demonstrates how you can add the "{" and "}" characters based on a class "active". I'm not sure what the HTML for your menu is, but the HTML structure I used is fairly standard for a menu.

This assumes you have a way to get an 'active' class on the active menu item (e.g: adding the class to the link during jQuery "click" event). If you need any help setting that up, mention something in the comments.

http://jsfiddle.net/smclark89/hD6GW/

HTML

```
<ul class="myMenu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And for the CSS:

```
/* These set up the menu layout, unrelated to adding "{" and "}". */
.myMenu { list-style-type:none; }
.myMenu li { display:inline-block; }

/* These add a "{" and a "}" before and after the link. */
.myMenu li.active a:before { content: "{"; }
.myMenu li.active a:after { content: "}"; }
```

Comment: Great! Its also worth mentioning for anyone in the future that this approach probably won't work in IE7 and under as the :before and :after selectors aren't supported by these browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're calling active. As soon as you identify the item - you can modify it via pure CSS using `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes

For example this demo does this to a focused element: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2rWJ/